# Owncloud installation issue with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cloud, owncloud

I'm trying to install OC on IIS + PHP + PostgreSQL and I've ran into problems.

When I enter all the install information (admin account, database connection information) I get:

> Error while trying to create admin user: could not find driver

What I see as an issue is that OC is creating its own user in postgresql and then it can't connect using that user or what?

I also tried to use user account that OwnCloud created but then it says that PostGreSQL username/password is not corrent, just like user doesn't exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the line: php_pdo_pgsql.dll in php.ini.

This is a possible solution according to http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=22631 which describes a comparable problem.

Comment: PHP 5.3 doesn't have php_pdo_pgsql.dll . Only extension=php_pgsql.dll

Comment: Did you enable that one?